# Performance limit - utilization is toggled to Yes always is this completely normal?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, performance, gpu

What does this performance limit utilization mean at the GPU section?

It's permanently set to Yes. Sometime passes when I'm idle even when I game it still does not go away. Idk what else happens but my games are buttery smooth no issues and all that. I think it was already set to yes but I just discovered it.

I see nothing wrong with my clocks everything is as stated. No drops in performance all is working well. It's just that it's Yes always and it's the only one on the Performance Limit GPU section that's toggled to yes and nothing else. Got this GPU 2 days ago and brand new.

I'm really curious as to what this means and is it generally normal? I did not do any overclocking when it came to my system just all default.

GPU: GTX 1660 Super Inno3D Twin X2

I use HWiNFO to check everything, temps, clocks, etc and the utilization is normal.

[image]

Comment: Where do you see this "Yes" ? A screenshot would be useful.

Comment: Right here, i marked it
https://imgur.com/WfgRZDn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that there's not enough load (utilization) on the GPU
for it to drive its clocks higher, hence the clock is limited to
a lower state.

The GPU will stop this limitation and will draw more power when its
workload will increase.

In other words, you're not placing a heavy load on the GPU, so it
does not need to boost its performance.

This is absolutely normal and a good indication that your GPU is trying
to economize on electric power usage.

Source : HWINFO forum
[Performance Limit - Utilization permanently on Yes](https://www.hwinfo.com/forum/threads/performance-limit-utilization-permanently-on-yes.6150/).

Comment: Well good to know! i thought for a second that i did something wrong. But i didn't do anything after noticing it that it was on Yes. I simply just monitored to see what happens. Welp this card has been pleasingly easy to take care of and game on. This has been a wonderful day.